# Generating Pareto observations using the inverse cumulative distribution

Tags: distribution, inverse, uniform-distribution

I'm currently working on an assignment in which you have to generate Pareto observations using the inverse cumulative function of the Pareto distribution. I have never managed to actually inverse a statistical function before, and I can't really seem to get it right. I understand the formula X=F^1(U), where X is the Pareto distributed random variable and U is a standard uniform random variable are important for generating observations, but I can't figure out on how to compute the inverse function.

I was hoping on some insight on how to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

- Write down the formula for F(X).
- Write "= U" to the right of the formula.
- Use algebra to isolate a single value X on the left-hand side of your equation, i.e., solve for X as a function of U.

The resulting equation is the inversion formula.  Now do a "sanity check" by plugging in a few values of U: 0 to get the min, 1 to get the max, and 0.5 to get the median.

Example:  A Uniform(a, b) has CDF `F(x) = (x - a) / (b - a)` for a ≤ x ≤ b, and has min a, max b, and median (a + b) / 2.

- F(X) = (X - a) / (b - a)
- (X - a) / (b - a) = U
- X - a = (b - a) U
- X = a + (b - a) U

Test cases:

- U = 0 => a + (b - a) 0 = a
- U = 1 => a + (b - a) 1 = a + b - a = b
- U = 0.5 => a + (b - a) / 2 = (2a + b - a) / 2 = (a + b) / 2

Implementation (in Ruby, since you didn't specify a language):

```
def uniform(a, b)
  return a + (b - a) * rand        # rand with no arguments returns a U(0,1)
end
```